# Retrieving Kodi MAC address shows 00:00:00:00:00

Tags: android, networking, mac-address, android-tv, kodi

I am using an add on for Kodi that retrieves the MAC address from the android device.  This is used to verify the install on the correct device.
With Android TV boxes running lollipop and marshmallow it seems to be working correctly, but on tablets and phones it returns 00:00:00:00:00 as the MAC address, which obviously is not correct.   Any suggestions on how to fix this or get around it?

Answer (score 0):

`00:00:00:00:00` returns as the MAC address when vmware instances are started and left unconfigured they originate frames with all 0 source address. You can check it in this [thread](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10895666/invalid-source-mac-address-000000000000). Here's another post which might help: [What could these IP addresses with MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 be?](https://superuser.com/questions/821802/what-could-these-ip-addresses-with-mac-000000000000-be)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the answer doesn't address the issue I'm having.  I'm using a Kodi add on (python code) to check the MAC address of the device it's installed on.  The method call from Kodi is  
    xbmc.getInfoLabel("network.macaddress")    and it returns 00:00:00:00:00 in phones and tablets.  It works fine on Android boxes with 6.0 or earlier installed